# how to create tables in relationships

Tags: mysql, database

[image: DB Design]

**Problem :** In above UI pic for my application when i select build in Team the Category should show items related only to build , the same way when i select Acquire in Category only items related to acquire should show up in Sub - Category.

I have to populate these UI elements from a SQL DB .

I dont know  how to relate this and create tables.

I know bit of DB basic but design is new to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Team, Field tName

Table Category, Field tName, catName

Table Sub, Field catname, Subname

when you select team, set 'where' for Category and requery

when you select Category, set 'where' for Sub and requery.